# How could Cameron recover from electrocution?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In [2x20 To the Lighthouse](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_220:_To_the_Lighthouse), Cameron

> went to save the kidnapped Derek but got drought in a liquid and then got electrocuted.

However, it did not take her the two minutes a reboot apparently takes (even for her, as was shown previously in a flashback in [2x12 Alpine Fields](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_212:_Alpine_Fields) where she

> got knocked out by the T-888 who tried to kill Sydney's mother.

So what happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Sarah said in "Alpine Fields", the electrocution trick doesn't always work.  She was likely referring to their attempt to extract Cameron's chip in "Samson and Delilah".  In that episode, Cameron collapsed after being electrocuted but was down for less than a minute before regaining consciousness.  She awoke while John was trying to pry open the CPU port cover, forcing him and Sarah to flee.

The natural conclusion to draw is that the same sort of thing happened in "To The Lighthouse"; Cameron didn't need a full restart.  Note that even with our much simpler systems today, computers take variable amounts of time to boot, depending on factors like filesystem corruption and whether peripherals and busses can be initialized in parallel or must be set up sequentially.

Comment: I somehow assumed in "Samson and Delilah" John simply wasn't quick enough and Cameron needed her two minutes, but I guess it makes sense...